# Apply a jQuery function live() in 1 object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a Facebook-Like Chat. (You can see it @ http://www.live-pin.com/). It gets the last messages from a JSON file and inserts into an individual UL for each user, it before checks if the ul exists and if it doesnt, it creates. Now the problem is that when I click on 1 chat bar, the 3 open at the same time, and only close if I click on the last one, what can I do? I want that this bars only open/close when clicked on chat bar but doesnt if click on not_clickable. Thanks for your help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
getOnJSON();
setInterval("getOnJSON()", 60000);

var Id;
var target;
});


    function showChat(obj){
        $(obj).animate({marginBottom : "0"}).removeClass("hidden_box").addClass("active_box").unbind('click')/*.click(function(){
           hideChat(this);
        })*/;

    }
    function hideChat(obj){
        $(obj).animate({marginBottom : "-270px"}).removeClass("active_box").addClass("hidden_box").unbind('click')/*.click(function(){
           showChat(this);
        })*/;
    }


    function getOnJSON(){

    var self = this;     // Added this line, as this changes scope in each()
    var from;var to;var msg_id;var msg_txt;var new_chat_string;

    //Getting the data from the json file
    $.getJSON("/ajax/chat.json.php",function(data){

    $.each(data.notif, function(i,data){

    from = data.from;to = data.to;msg_id = data.id;msg_txt = data.text;

            if ($("#chat_"+from+"_lp").length === 0){
            $("#boxes").append('<div id="chat_'+from+'_lp" class="chat_box hidden_box clickable_box"><div id="chat_'+from+'_nick" class="chat_name">'+from+'</div><div class="not_clickable"><ul id="chat_'+from+'_txt" class="chat_txt"><li id="' + msg_id + '">'+ msg_txt+'</li></ul><form class="chat_new_message" name="new_msg"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your message..." class="chat_new_input"/></form></div></div>');    

$('.hidden_box #chat_'+from+'_nick').live("click", function(){ showChat('#chat_'+from+'_lp'); });
$('.active_box #chat_'+from+'_nick').live("click", function(){ hideChat('#chat_'+from+'_lp'); });
        }else{

            $("#chat_"+from+"_txt").append('<li id="' + msg_id + '">'+ msg_txt+'</li>');

$('.hidden_box #chat_'+from+'_nick').live("click", function(){ showChat('#chat_'+from+'_lp'); });
$('.active_box #chat_'+from+'_nick').live("click", function(){ hideChat('#chat_'+from+'_lp'); });
        }
    });
});
}
```

Comment: fyi, excessive commenting does *not* make code more readable

Comment: Why so many unnecesary comments? It makes it quite hard to read.

Comment: What is not working? Please describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: I detailed it more, sorry for the highnumber-comments

Comment: FYI, `.live()` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use jquery .live() function for your .click() to be applied to elements created after the document load complete.

For instance: `$("a.offsite").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); });` is an example from [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: thanks, this is supposed to work but it doesn't. [Enter this site ---](http://live-pin.com) you can see the code implemented there but it doesn't work!

Comment: is the box in the corner with the word 'new' a chat you are loading?

Comment: Okay, and if you put 'this' instead of 'self' in the live()?

Comment: maybe try fixing your id="" tag... you have 2 ids within each and the id is not unique from other elements on the page. also try to make anything happen to it, ex. instead of showChat(this) do $(this).css('backgroundColor','yellow') instead of calling the function. If you can get it to work without the function, then try calling the function. Check with alert(this); to see if the object is still defined.

Comment: Sorry, it was not planned to be a space, I fixed it and not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7567/discussion-between-scott-and-luis)